# Host React and Express on the same server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am working on a react site that has a contact page. On the contact page there is a text field where you enter a message that will be sent to a specific email address.

Right now I'm just trying to set up express with my react app, the *only* thing I need Express for is this one feature.

In my react app I am doing

```
$.post('http://localhost:3030/API',{value:'hi'}, function(result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

And in my Express `index.js` file I'm doing

```
app.get('/API', (request, response) => {  
  console.log(request);
})
```

Just as a simple test to see if things are working properly.

When I run these both and attempt to execute my `post` function, I get the `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` error, which is basically saying that I [can't make a request to a separate domain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). The issue here is not that error, but the fact that I am running my Express server and react app on two different servers.

Is there a way to have them on the same server? I am very new to back-end development, any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: It's really not that difficult, just have your express app serve up the HTML for your React app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, React runs on the client and Express is a Node.js framework. There's a pretty good chance you're using Express if you're running any boilerplate.

Here's a pretty good walkthrough on more complete routing.
https://medium.com/@patriciolpezjuri/using-create-react-app-with-react-router-express-js-8fa658bf892d

In several of my applications my routes look something like this:

```
//router.js--and I'm positive this is from some react-express boilerplate
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

const react =  (req, res, next)=>{
  res.render('react', { 
    title: 'React Application',
    layout: false
  });
};

router.get('/app', react);
router.get('/app*', react);
module.exports = router;

//app.js
...
app.use('/', routes); //<--this is the exported router. 
...
```

If you want to be more simple it is probably something like:

```
   let reactRoute = (request, response, next) => {
     //render your react page however you're doing that. 
   }
   express.use('/API', yourApiFunction)
   express.use('/', reactRoute)
   express.use('/*', reactRoute) //Wildcards are REALLY important if you're routing inside react.
```

You can also bypass things with a proxy but that tends to get more complex than you probably want. Also--keep in mind you don't have to stick to Node on the back-end if you're not comfortable with it. React is client side, I use it with a few production .NET apps, some PHP (lordy!), and, yes, a lot of Node servers.

Answer (score -1):

to solve `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`
you've to use the cors middleware

go to the term
`yarn add cors` or `npm i cors`

in `server.js`

```
const cors = require("cors");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
```